# Uso de LIKE en expresiones finales, EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Tengo una tabla que tiene los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para encontrar este dato utilizo esta sentencia:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[orden]
      ,[fecha]
      ,[componente]
      ,[unidades]
      ,[material]
      ,[cortadoBy]
      ,[metros]
  FROM [Cortes].[dbo].[ControlScrap]
  where orden='GORE-5850' AND unidades LIKE '_-2'
```

Quiero y debo usar el `LIKE` "`_-`X" por que necesito encontrar lo que esta detrás del guion, puesto que estoy utilizando EF, cual seria su equivalencia?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Tienes hecho algo en EF? De ser afirmativo, incluye en tu pregunta por favor :D

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si te refieres a esto
FROM [Cortes].[dbo].[ControlScrap] where orden='GORE-5850' AND unidades LIKE '%_-2'

Comment: no entiendo tu respuesta

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. Es un comentario a la pregunta, debes esperar a tener un mínimo de reputación para poder comentar en preguntas de otras personas, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y buscar alguna pregunta que te quede clara para responder sin requerir aclaraciones, o publicar alguna pregunta, para ganar esos primeros puntos de reputación. Un saludo y bienvenido/a a StackOverflow.